# Closing a question as a duplicate -> exact match or answer that explains the background

Tags: discussion, support

I had this situation two times in the younger past, and am wondering what the common approach to this is.

The first question [Comparing unique items in arrays using Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509980/comparing-unique-items-in-arrays-using-set#comment70225862_41509980), which is marked as a duplicate of 3 different questions. I voted to close it as a duplicate of this question: [Why are two identical objects not equal to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704971/why-are-two-identical-objects-not-equal-to-each-other), allthough that question/answer doesn't explain the OP's question, but explains the general background of why two objects are never similiar to each other, which the OP obviously didn't know, but he could have solved his issue alone by understanding this. In addition, I edited the automatic comment and added a link to an answer explaining how to compare objects in javascript.

The second question [Value of variable outside $.get call not been set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447670/value-of-variable-outside-get-call-not-been-set) is a question asking about help for returning from an async function, though the OP just did not call the callback. I voted to close that question as a duplicate of this answer [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/3993662), which explains pretty much everything about handling asynchronity in javascript. Like the first duplicate vote, that answer doesn't explicitly answer the OP's question, but by reading and understanding the linked answer, OP will never make the same mistake again and could choose of a set of possibilities -> he would really learn something.

So what is the consensus on this? Strictly vote to close for really exact matches, or is my approach acceptable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With regard to [Comparing unique items in arrays using Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509980/comparing-unique-items-in-arrays-using-set#comment70225862_41509980), it's not at all of a dup of question talking about object equality, as made clear by not only the title

> Comparing unique items in arrays using Set

but also the content of the question. The underlying question was how to detect that all array items are the same. In a failed attempt to solve that, the OP misused/misunderstood object equality. It's true that due to some poor wording, the question *could* be interpreted as asking about object equality:

> The following code [using object equality] seems like it should work, but it doesn't. *Can anyone explain?*

So the "can anyone explain" part can be interpreted as the question being why `[] != []`, if one ignores the question asked in the title. It's true that the OP did not understand this. But it's not true that understanding it would necessarily help him solve his problem--it would merely help him understand why one particular attempt didn't work. Therefore, it's not the case that this question is a duplicate of a question which simply answers why a particular approach he tried didn't work.

The larger context makes it clear that his real question was how to determine that all elements of an array are identical using JavaScript `Set`.

Before seeing this meta post, I actually reopened the question.

---

To clarify, let me break down the question and possible answers as follows:

> Problem as stated in title: **Comparing unique items in arrays using Set** (would better read "Detecting all items in array are identical")

Possible solutions:

1. Don't use `Set`. This approach might be simplest (`array.every(x => x === array[0])`), but would seem to be out of scope given the question title.
2. Use `Set` (by creating a `Set` from the input array).

   2.1. Check that the size of the set is 1 (`new Set(array).size === 1`). **This would seem to be the simplest, most obvious solution.**

   2.2. Check that the set is "equal" to a set created with a single element (`new Set([array[0]])`). This is what the OP did in his attempt.

   2.2.1. Try using `==` to check set equality. This doesn't work, because `==` does not check deep equality. The question was originally closed as a duplicate of [one which explains this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704971/why-are-two-identical-objects-not-equal-to-each-other). However, the question here is not really a duplicate of that one. That proposed dup target merely describes why this particular attempt by the OP does not work.

   2.2.2. Try some other approach to checking set equality. A comment on the question suggested [another question which explains how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128855/comparing-ecma6-sets-for-equality) as a dup target. However, the question here is not really a dup of that question either, since all it actually does is to explain how to correctly implement a flawed, inefficient, unnecessary solution to the problem. However, the OP edited his post to say "Edit: The link provided below by faintsignal is the most applicable answer. It not only explains why this behavior occurs but offers a solution to the stated problem.". But actually, this is **not** the most applicable answer. Although it does explain why the behavior encountered in one attempt to solve the problem occurs, and does "offer a [particular] solution to the stated problem", that is not the **best** solution. In fact, doing deep-equality checking on a set created from an array against a set created from its first element as a way of checking if all the array elements are identical is a horrible solution. The mere fact that the OP thought it was a good solution--perhaps missing the comment suggesting the approach of checking if the size was one--does **not** imply that that is necessarily the right dup target.

To restate this in terms of the definition of dup targets, the relevant question would be "Is this question a dup of some other question by virtue of the latter question (proposed dup target) explaining why a particular sub-optimal solution presented by the OP doesn't work or how to fix it?".